# starting container process caused "process_linux.go:303: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused \"EOF\"": unknown

Tags: kubernetes

Today when I start kubernetes(v1.15) pod, show this error:

```
Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "soa-user-service-7bf6d9886b-vd422": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:303: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused \"EOF\"": unknown
```

I tried execute this command in host(`CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)`):

```
[root@uat-k8s-02 ~]# sysctl -w user.max_user_namespaces=15000
user.max_user_namespaces = 15000
```

but the problem still exists. what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Docker related issue. Almost each time on Centos
Please take a look here:

- [OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:303: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused "EOF"": unknown" #87735](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/87735)
- [docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:319: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused "EOF"": unknown. #1963](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/1963)
- [Cannot start container: Getting the final child's pid from pipe caused "EOF"](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40835)

Ways to resolve:

- In each case helps [systemctl restart docker.service](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/87735#issuecomment-675216935)

If you are using GKE, you can check if below is correct in your configuration. [Source comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40835#issuecomment-649216095).

```
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1100m
            memory: 3000m  # correct: 3000M
          requests:
            cpu: 1100m
            memory: 3000m # correct: 3000M
```